# Cannot resolve symbol 'DividerItemDecoration'

Tags: java, android

So I wanted to add a 'DividerItemDecoration' to my recycler view, but it keeps saying `Cannot resolve symbol 'DividerItemDecoration'`. I solved this by making my own DividerItemDecoration class. Now I want to add a SnapHelper to my recycler view and its giving me the same error. My grade dependencies are up to date. I tried **Invalidate Caches/Restart** but it didn't help. Thoughts?

```
package osoble.bloodhero.Fragments;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import android.support.v7.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import android.support.v7.widget.SnapHelper;

import osoble.bloodhero.Adapters.BloodBankAdapter;
import osoble.bloodhero.Models.BloodBank;
import osoble.bloodhero.R;

public class BloodBankAppointmentFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = BloodBankAppointmentFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private RecyclerView bloodbankRecyclerView;
    private BloodBankAdapter mAdapter;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
    private DatabaseReference childRef;
    private ProgressDialog progress;

    public BloodBankAppointmentFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.blood_bank_appointment, container, false);
        Log.i(TAG, "Was Opened");

        getActivity().setTitle("Set Appointment");
        bloodbankRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.r_blood_bank_search);
        bloodbankRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));

        progress = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        progress.setMessage("Loading...");
        progress.setCancelable(false);
        progress.show();

//        SnapHelper snapHelperStart = new GravitySnapHelper(Gravity.START);

        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabaseRef.keepSynced(true);
        childRef = mDatabaseRef.child("Blood Bank");

        childRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                progress.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        mAdapter = new BloodBankAdapter(BloodBank.class, R.layout.blood_bank_row,
                BloodBankAdapter.BloodBankViewHolder.class, childRef, getContext());

        bloodbankRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        bloodbankRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        bloodbankRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(
                new DividerItemDecoration(bloodbankRecyclerView.getContext(), 3)
        );

        return view;

    }

}
```

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "osoble.bloodhero"
        minSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.github.rubensousa:gravitysnaphelper:1.3'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
    compile 'devs.mulham.horizontalcalendar:horizontalcalendar:1.2.0'
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '24.1.0'
            }
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: show code please.

Comment: RecyclerView.ItemDecoration is the class for Divider. DividerItemDecoration is customization if it .

Comment: Please provide code.

Answer (score 0):

U can use this SpacesItemDecoration instead of DividerItemDecoration for RecyclerView

```
package com.tijoyoutubes.helper;

import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;

public class SpacesItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
private int space;

public SpacesItemDecoration(int space) {
this.space = space;
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, 
  RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
outRect.left = space;
outRect.right = space;
outRect.bottom = space;

// Add top margin only for the first item to avoid double space between items
if (parent.getChildLayoutPosition(view) == 0) {
    outRect.top = space;
} else {
    outRect.top = 0;
}
 }
}
```

And use

`int spacingInPixels = 2;// getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.spacing);
        recyclerView
                .addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(spacingInPixels));`

for implementation

Answer (score 0):

I had to change from

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "sajilni.com.retrofit2httpclient"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

To this ( changed from min SDK **15 to 25** )

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.chikeandroid.retrofittutorial"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

So the reason its not supported in old SDK , its that simple

**Or what i did** because i needed support for IceCream 15 API till now a days version!

[image: sample what i have after this]

I adopted this solution
[StackOverFlow AnswerAndroid RecyclerView addItemDecoration Won't Add Decoration to Bottom of RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42591746/944593)

**BTW** I was following this tutorial to implement
[Get Started With Retrofit 2 HTTP Client](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-retrofit-2--cms-27792)